# How to create hyperlink in IBM Cognos for data passing

Tags: hyperlink, cognos

I am new to Cognos, and using version 10.2.2.

I have a list report (Report A) with drill down to another report (Report B) implemented through parameter passing.

I have to create a hyperlink back to Report A inside of Report B. I have tried the following three approaches for setting the hyperlink value:

```
~run.prompt=false&p_paramA=[Query1].[DataItemA]
~run.prompt=false&p_paramA=trim([Query1].[DataItemA])
"~run.prompt=false&p_paramA="+ParamDisplayValue([Query1].[DataItemA])
```

All of the above failed, and only a hard-coded value works:
`~run.prompt=false&p_paramA=ABC`

Is there any method that can have a link back to the pervious report?

I have also tried to add a text Item with drill down, but it cannot read the data items from `[Query1]`, and it shows empty for the drill down parameter option in the newly created text Item.

Note: Browser "back" button cannot be used because the chart/visualisation fails to show.

Comment: You mention a "periods report" but do not define what that is.  Also, you mention that a hard-coded value works.  You should put that in the question for reference.  PS: I have edited your question, please wait for the edit to be approved (or you can approve it yourself if you see fit).

Comment: Sorry for typing mistake, should be 'previous' report, added the worked one for reference

Answer (score 1):

Change Source Type for Hyperlink to Data Item Value add new Data Item to your query with expression like

```
'~run.prompt=false&p_paramA='+[Query1].[DataItemA]
```

Then use this Data Item for Hyperlink

Comment: thanks!! but it shows **The variable named '[Query1].[DataItemA]' is invalid**

Comment: A yes. Sorry. Try to change Source type to Data Item Value and add new Data Item with value above to your Query.

Comment: thanks a lot, sorry for a extra question, I find hyperlink not works on iPad Cognos apps, is there any method I can create a text/button link to reports that will works on both browser an iPad? thanks!!!!!!!!!

Comment: iPad app isn't a browser. I'm not sure it is possible.